# iPhone 5s locked and erased by third person

Tags: iphone, apple-id, activation-lock

My son's iPhone 5s was locked and erased by someone he shared a cloud with during a work project. This phone was never on this man's account. I have a receipt as proof of ownership. I also have the email originally placing the Apple ID and cloud info. I bought the phone new from AT&T and had have it on my account for the past year.

The person we assume did this denies locking the device maliciously or accidentally.

Apple refuses to unlock the phone and won't even tell who or what Apple ID locked the phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can activate the iPhone which is asking for credentials I don't remember?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164859/how-i-can-activate-the-iphone-which-is-asking-for-credentials-i-dont-remember)

Comment: On what grounds did Apple refuse to unlock the device? I'm going to edit this so it doesn't get closed again as too broad once you've added these details. Just edit in the missing details and the hold will be reviewed and possible released. It seems Apple needs time to research if you are the owner. Is the refusal there final?